# Why do I get error code 800a03ea and 80040e14 from two lines of SQL code?

Tags: sql-server

I don't know if this is the proper place for this but here goes...

It all started about a year and a half ago. In about last April, our SQL Server (SQL Server 2014 running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine) suddenly took offense at a couple of lines of code that it had tolerated for years.

This line of code:

```vb
sqlstr2 = "INSERT INTO NewsGameBigQuestionsByPoints (OnePoint, TwoPoints, ThreePoints, FourPoints, CategoryID) values ('"
sqlstr2 = sqlstr2 & strOnePointQuestionInsert & "', '" & strTwoPointsQuestionInsert & "', '" & strThreePointsQuestionInsert & "', '" & strFourPointsQuestionInsert & "',"& lngCategoryID & ");"
MyConn.Execute(sqlstr2)
```

Suddenly generated this error:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ea'
> Syntax error
> /cassadmin/Big/newgame.asp, line 109**

And this line of code:

```vb
Sqlstr3 = "UPDATE NewsGameBigAnswersByPoints SET "
sqlstr3 = sqlstr3 &" OnePointA='" & strOnePointAnswerInsertA & "', TwoPointsA='" & strTwoPointsAnswerInsertA & "', ThreePointsA='" & strThreePointsAnswerInsertA & "', FourPointsA='" & strFourPointsAnswerInsertA & "' "
sqlstr3 = sqlstr3 &", OnePointB='" & strOnePointAnswerInsertB & "', TwoPointsB='" & strTwoPointsAnswerInsertB & "', ThreePointsB='" & strThreePointsAnswerInsertB & "', FourPointsB='" & strFourPointsAnswerInsertB & "' "   sqlstr3 = sqlstr3 &", OnePointC='" & strOnePointAnswerInsertC & "', TwoPointsC='" & strTwoPointsAnswerInsertC & "', ThreePointsC='" & strThreePointsAnswerInsertC & "', FourPointsC='" & strFourPointsAnswerInsertC & "' "
sqlstr3 = sqlstr3 &", OnePointCORRECT='" & strOnePointAnswerInsertCORRECT & "', TwoPointsCORRECT='" & strTwoPointsAnswerInsertCORRECT & "', ThreePointsCORRECT='" & strThreePointsAnswerInsertCORRECT & "', FourPointsCORRECT='" & strFourPointsAnswerInsertCORRECT & "' "
sqlstr3 = sqlstr3 & " WHERE CategoryID="& lngCategoryID &";"
```

at the same time generated this error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.
> cassadminBignewgame.asp, line 111

I looked over the code closely but don't know enough about SQL code to have spotted any but the most glaring errors (of which I found none).

Since these two errors popped up at the same time, and all of a sudden, I began to think they might be related to an OBDC driver update we had then recently installed.

I tried to go back to the driver (one of the 17s) we had been using before the problem but that was a disaster. It turns out that the web is just chock full of instructions on how to install or deinstall ODBC drivers. All different and, it seems, all ineffective.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

I looked over the code and didn't find any glaring errors (I.e. an odd number of quotes or parentheses)

I then tried to break up these two lines of code into more but smaller lines.

I then replaced the version 18 ODBC driver with a version 17. No joy, I had really been hoping it was a driver issue but apparently not so.

So, I'm out of solutions.

Comment: The better question; why are you injecting your parameters and not parameterising them?

Comment: First error looks like vb error though, not sql.

Comment: What do you think will happen to your queries if the incoming data has a single quote in it? E.g. `David O'Brien`